# Edit nested list in python 3

Tags: python, list, nested, flatten, unnest

How do I unnest a nested list or flatten a nested list.

so that,

```
servers  = [["10.10.10.10" , "20.20.20.20"] ,["30.30.30.30"] , ["40.40.40.40", "50.50.50.50"] , ["60.60.60.60"],["70.70.70.70"]]
```

becomes,

```
servers  = ["10.10.10.10" , "20.20.20.20"] ,["30.30.30.30"] , ["40.40.40.40", "50.50.50.50"] , ["60.60.60.60"],["70.70.70.70"]
```

All help welcome thanks

Comment: would [`servers = list(chain(*servers))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) suffice?

Answer (score 2):

But what type of data do you expect? By defining

```
x = item1, item2
```

You get a tuple. You can convert list to tuple by

```
servers = tuple(servers)
```

That gives you:

```
 (["10.10.10.10" , "20.20.20.20"] ,["30.30.30.30"] , ["40.40.40.40", "50.50.50.50"] , ["60.60.60.60"],["70.70.70.70"])
```

Or you can flatten you list:

```
servers = [el for item in servers for el in item]
```

But then you will get:

```
["10.10.10.10" , "20.20.20.20" ,"30.30.30.30" , "40.40.40.40", "50.50.50.50" , "60.60.60.60","70.70.70.70"]
```

Comment: I just needed to "loose" the outer brackets so I could zip the list to another list. I never realized I could use the tuple command. completely flattening the list is not in scope for what i'm trying to achieve as I intend to use the zip function later on.

Answer (score 0):

you simply cannot have that way. 
when you say

```
a = 1, 2, 3
print(a)
```

it outputs

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

so you can either has a tuple or a list but not without () or []